# Next page token keeps returning same results and same nextpagetoken

Tags: oauth2-playground

I've seen similar threads about this issue, but I don't think timing is the issue, as there are long delays between requests.  In Oauth 2.0 playground, I authorize the following API:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly

I get the access token and configure and execute the following request:

https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/chromeos

In the JSON response, there is the nextPageToken key.  I take the key and construct a new request:

https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/chromeos?pagetoken=ClkaUwozqgEwCi4wLDI1MjI0MDY4NDQsMjE4NTM1OSwidjE6MDMzMTg1MjUwNTU3MjY2MTM3MDEiIhxjZG1fZGV2aWNlLmRkc19zb3J0X2tleSBkZXNjSAFQABoCEgA

When I execute this request, I get the same set of results.  However, in the API explorer,

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/list

I can execute the same query, get a JSON response, and get the same nextPageToken, and then add that in the pagetoken parameter, re-execute, and now I get the next page of results.  This also works for me when coded directly in Apps Script using the native interfaces.  However, if I use the Oauth 2.0 Apps Script library, it behaves exactly like the OAuth 2.0 playground.  That is, I can get the initial set of results, but any further URLfetches with the pagetoken paraemeter set to nextpagetoken just keeps bringing up the same results over and over.

Here's why I don't think this is a timing issue.  I wait a minute between each request in OAuth playground AND the API explorer.  Yet, one works, the other doesn't.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured this out.  The right parameter isn't pagetoken, but pageToken.  CAPS matter.  Geezus.